# Subdirectory domain mapping on WordPress multisite

Tags: wordpress, dns, adsense

I have a WordPress installation with multisite support enabled. Currently I have 50 websites using the sub-directory option when I configured the multisite support. That means that each site is accessed like this:

```
http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/site1
....
http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/site50
```

***Where aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd is the IP address of the computer that I use for a host.***

I bought 50 domains and mapped them to the IP address. Then I configured the directory mapping using a plugins so each site has its own domain. Now I have this mapping:

```
http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/site1  -> http://mydomain1.com
....
http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/site50 -> http://mydomain50.com
```

Which means that when the user enters for example: **http://mydomain2.com** in the browser's address bar the **http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/site50** site gets loaded. (But the mdomain2.com name stays in the address bar)

So lets get now to the question I have:

Is it possible that somebody finds out that I use this kind of mapping and how my host is organized?

The reason I ask is because I want to use independent advertising accounts ( Google adsense) for each of the 50 sites (which are on the same computer) and what worries me if some of the account gets banned is it somehow possible that the rest 49 get affected?

I want the only thing which is common between these websites to be the IP address on which are hosted. Everything else should be completely independent!

Answer (score 0):

It's won't say it's *impossible* to figure it out, but it would be rather difficult. Generally speaking though you shouldn't have to worry about this in most cases - there are many hosting providers that serve multiple clients/domain names from a common host/IP address. That said, if one of the sites is hosting porn/malware/other banned content, it is possible that the IP address will be added to filtering blacklists - NetNanny and the like - in which case all of the sites may be inaccessible to users accessing the Internet through one of these filters.

For your case I would say it is unlikely that you will run into problems. I have multiple sites hosted on the same IP address and one of them was banned from AdSense but the others were not. Your mileage may vary however.